# Emails are only delivered to major mail services

Tags: dns, email, webmail

I have installed mailEnable on my own dedicated server and did some setup. Webmail is working. I can receive emails and also send email but the sent mails fail to reach to some mail servers. Sending email to **gmail**, **yahoo** etc. is OK but sent mails to other small companies are not being delivered. We receive no error when sending emails but target persons say that there was no mail is being received (even spam). Is there some incorrect settings in our DNS settings or dmarc policy or I should check something else?

Here is dns settings for my domain `example.com`

**MX record:**

- FQDN: example.com
- FQDN of mail server: webmail.example.com.

**two txt records:**

- v=DMARC1;p=none;rua=mailto:info@example.com;fo=1
- v=spf1 -all

**dmarc record (txt):**

- record name: _dmarc
- FQDN: _dmarc.example.com
- text: v=DMARC1;p=none;rua=mailto:info@example.com;fo=1

**A record:**

- host: webmail
- FQDN: webmail.example.com
- IP address: 88.99.222.3 (this is sample)

Answer (score 3):

Your emails are not being delivered because **your SPF record is currently set to disallow all outgoing mail**. Major email services rely on heuristics other than SPF to detect unwanted mail such as content matching and machine learning, but smaller providers are more likely to take your SPF record at its word and reject all email from your domain.

So your current record:

`v=spf1 -all`

needs to be changed to include the approved IP addresses and/or domains for sending outgoing mail:

`v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.x ip6:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x include:example.com -all`

Since you are hosting your own email server, you will just want to use the IP address(es) that your server is sending via SMTP from, likely resulting in a record of this form:

`v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.x -all`

Comment: thank you. Is that spf. mandatory before email provider domain? or this is ok? `v=spf1 include:88.99.222.3 -all`

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I re-read your question and noticed that you are using your own mail server. I edited my answer accordingly. Use the `ipv4` or `ipv6` directives for IP addresses, the `include` directive is only for delegating to other domains.

Comment: Thank you. Let me check if this solves the problem

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Don't forget to wait out the DNS TTL!